# OSGI JavaMail Service

Tags: service, osgi, jakarta-mail, blueprint-osgi, karaf

I have problems to declare an e-mail session as an OSGI service.
I am using Apache Karaf 3.0.1 as container, Apache Aries for the blueprint JPA and JNDI enhancement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

  <bean id="mailSession" class="javax.mail.Session" init-method="getInstance">
      <property name="mail.smtp.host" value="mysmptpip"/>
      <property name="mail.smtp.port" value="25"/>
  </bean>

  <service auto-export="interfaces" ref="mailSession">
    <service-properties>
      <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="java:mail/MailSession"/>
    </service-properties>
  </service>
</blueprint>
```

I have an error of type enable to find a matching method on class javax.mail.Session for arguments `[{mail.smtp.host=mysmptpip, mail.smtp.port=25}]` ...

Does anybody have any idea how this should be fixed ?

In addtion I would like to know how can I declare a JavaMail session as a JNDI resource via Apache blueprint (that will create the service)?

Comment: I don't agree with closing this question. It is not opinion based. The author just has an error in his blueprint xml. The correct bean definition should look something like this:
    <bean class="javax.mail.Session" factory-method="getInstance">
     <argument type="java.util.Properties">
      <props>
       <prop key="mail.smtp.host">mysmptpip</prop>
       <prop key="mail.smtp.port">25</prop>
      </props>
     </argument>
    </bean>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could provide a configured mail Session as a service. So the configuration would be centralized.

Answer (score 0):

`BundleContext#registerService()` suffices; you can add properties to the service registration  if you want to, but it's not necessary. Remember to unregister the service when it's closed.